# Mustache.js splits HTML attibuts between whitespaces

Tags: javascript, html, mustache

Mustache.js splits an HTML attribut between many HTML attributs between whitespaces. How can I keep the attribut as it is ?

**The Object to render** (width contains whitespaces)

```
cardpool = {
   width:"col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 col-sm-4"
 }
```

**The template to use**

```
<div class={{width}}>
</div>
```

**The wrong result** (Mustache.js splits the attributs between the whitespaces) :

```
<div class="col-md-offset-3" col-md-6="" col-sm-4="">
</div>
```

**The expected result** (I want to keep the whitespaces in the attribut)

```
<div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 col-sm-4">
</div>
```

Do you have a solution to get the **expected result** ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you tried `class="{{width}}"`, with quotes?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi : Thank you it is the good answer to my problem !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't Mustache's fault. Your template is rendered to this:

```
<div class=col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 col-sm-4>
</div>
```

Notice the lack of any quotation marks around your class names. A browser can internally convert this to what you're seeing (I'm guessing that you are inspecting the generated data inside your browser's dev tools).

Your template should include the quotation marks around the variable if you want to group the class names into a single class attribute value:

```
<div class="{{width}}">
</div>
```

Mustache is (mostly) agnostic about the context in which it's used, so it doesn't know that attributes in HTML should be surrounded by quotation marks if the values contain whitespace. Hence, you need to add those yourself.

Comment: It's alright ! I forgot all quotation marks in all my Mustache templates. I thought that Mustache added the quotation marks but its wrong idea. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try with the triple mustache: `{{{width}}}`. This prevents HTML escaping, which it does if used as `{{width}}`.

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar Mustache.js, but ejs for example works like this :

```
<div class="<%= preRendData.class %>"></div>
```

So try your code with quotes :

```
<div class="{{width}}">
```